# How to come up with a function?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Say, I have a hypothetical value. And it increases at start and after some point it decreases (decays) at constant rate (average) and it tends to 0. It looks something like a Poisson distribution.

The question is: how do I come up with a function y(x)=? that will describe this behavior?

P.S.:If any data is missing, please give me a comment I'll try to provide it. This is a concrete question.

Comment: Will the function eventually reach zero?

Comment: @K.Stm.: yes, but you can assume whatever you want. My preference would be to see both cases so that I could understand how to deal with them.

Comment: You could try to fit $x^ae^{-bx}$ to your data, with positive $a,b$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

You can define a function similar to half life decay rate, which tends to $0$.

$N(t)=N_0(\dfrac{1}{2})^{\dfrac{t}{t_{1/2}}}$

And $t_{1/2}$ is the half-life. This might be helpful.

Comment: Yeah... it might be a part of it, but a) I need increase first and b) ideally it should cross x axis rather soon. For the decreasing part it is extremely easy to come up with something like: a-x*r (a=stationary point, r=rate of decrease). I guess I'll need to approximate it somehow using Taylor series.